# How to click on date picker for which the id keep changing on page refresh

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

in my page, I have 2 date picker side by side, & the class is the same for both, only the id is different & those id's also keeps changes on page refresh

**initial screen:**

(Date Picker-1)

```
<input type="text" id="rp-datepicker-1" max="10" name="rp-datepicker-1" placeholder="Enter MM/DD/YYYY" class="rp-datepicker-field rp-datepicker-1 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" xpath="1">
```

(Date Picker-2)

```
<input type="text" id="rp-datepicker-2" max="10" name="rp-datepicker-2" placeholder="Enter MM/DD/YYYY" class="rp-datepicker-field rp-datepicker-2 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" style="" xpath="1">
```

**After page refreshing the page**

(Date Picker-1)

```
<input type="text" id="rp-datepicker-5" max="10" name="rp-datepicker-5" placeholder="Enter MM/DD/YYYY" class="rp-datepicker-field rp-datepicker-5 ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" xpath="1">
```

(Date Picker-2)

```
<input type="text" id="rp-datepicker-6" max="10" name="rp-datepicker-6" placeholder="Enter MM/DD/YYYY" class="rp-datepicker-field rp-datepicker-6 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" xpath="1">
```

due to this change in id every time, the code is failing

Answer (score 0):

xpath

```
//input[contains(@id, 'rp-datepicker-')]
```

css

```
input[id^='rp-datepicker']
```